# Encrypting with RSA private key in Java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, private-key

I'm trying to encrypt some content with an RSA private key.

I'm following this example:
http://www.junkheap.net/content/public_key_encryption_java

but converting it to use private keys rather than public.  Following that example, I think what I need to do is:

- Read in a DER-format private key
- Generate a PCKS8EncodedKeySpec
- call generatePrivate() from KeyFactory to get a private key object
- Use that private key object with the Cipher object to do the encryption

So, the steps:

The key was generated from openssl with:

`openssl genrsa -aes256 -out private.pem 2048`

and then was converted to DER format with:

`openssl rsa -in private.pem -outform DER -out private.der`

I generate the PKCS8EncodedKeySpec with:

```
byte[] encodedKey = new byte[(int)inputKeyFile.length()];

try {
    new FileInputStream(inputKeyFile).read(encodedKey);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encodedKey);
return privateKeySpec;
```

And then generate the private key object with:

```
PrivateKey pk = null;

try {
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA_METHOD);
    pk = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return pk;
```

However, on the call to:

```
pk = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
```

I get:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Unknown key spec.
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JS_KeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(DashoA12275)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JSA_RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePrivate(DashoA12275)
at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePrivate(KeyFactory.java:237)
```

Questions:

- Is the general approach right?
- Is the PCKS8EncodedKeySpec the right keyspec to use?
- Any thoughts on the invalid key spec error?

Comment: I went through this one and generated them with Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19640735/load-public-key-data-from-file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, I'm confused why you are planning to use a `Cipher` to encrypt with a private key, rather than signing with a `Signature`. I'm not sure that all RSA `Cipher` providers will use the correct block type for setup, but it's worth a try.

Setting that aside, though, I think that you are trying to load a non-standard OpenSSL-format key. Converting it to DER with `rsa` is essentially just a base-64 decode; the structure of the key is not PKCS #8.

Instead, after `genrsa`, use the `openssl pkcs8` command to convert the generated key to unencrypted PKCS #8, DER format:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in private.pem -outform der -out private.der
```

This will produce an unencrypted private key that can be loaded with a `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`.

Comment: Honestly, I was unaware of Signature.

To make sure I understand its usage, I would initialize the signature object, call update with the bytes I want to sign, and then call sign?  And then I can store the bytes returned from sign as my digital signature?

Comment: Hello. Anyone finally resolved the problem? I have a privateKey That I cannot load into java to continue wiht signing phase. My privateKey is RSA, PKCS#8 DER and it has a password. How can I load that into java? The exception in my case is `java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException : DER input, Integer tag error`

Comment: @BRabbit27 To load a private key directly, it must be unencrypted. Use the `openssl pkcs8` command I show above, adding the option `-inform der`; it will prompt you for the password. If you want to keep your private key encrypted (**which I highly recommend**), you'll need to add it to a key store (like a PKCS #12 file), and access it through the `KeyStore` API in Java.

Comment: @erickson I tried the command but it shows an error (I'm using WinOpenSSL) **error decrypting key**. The command I used was `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in myKey.key -inform der -outform der -out myNoCryptKey.key`

Comment: **UPDATE** What's supposed to do the -nocrypt option? I think I made a workaround like this `openssl pkcs8 -inform DER -in myKey.key -outform PEM -out myKeyInPEM.key` it asked me for my password and then `openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in myKeyInPEM -outform DER -out myKeyInDERNoCrypted.key` it didn't ask my password but the result file seems equal to myKey.key

Comment: @BRabbit27 The -nocrypt option means that the output file will not be password encrypted. The file "seems" equal, or the file *is* equal? You can compute the hash of both files using OpenSSL, right?

Comment: @erickson seems equal. Actually I computed the hash and it's different. Finally I could load it from java. The only remaining questions are, why I have to pass from DER-Encrypted to PEM to DER-NoCrypt? For all the keys I have should I convert them to DER-NoCrypt to be able to load them from java? Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm not sure why you had to use the intermediate PEM file. I probably wouldn't be able to tell you without actually trying it myself with one of your keys. When I tried the process using my keys, I didn't have to go through that step.

Answer (score 11):

You can't encrypt with private key. If JCE allows you to do that, it's just by accident.

You need to use signature. Here are the code snippet to do that,

```
signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA");
signer.initSign(privateKey); // PKCS#8 is preferred
signer.update(dataToSign);
byte[] signature = signer.sign();
```

Comment: `s/public/private/` in your first line.

Answer (score 4):

Its not an accident that encryption with private key is allowed. If you want to break a signature into individual hashing and encryption, then encrypting with private key is essential. 
Lets say I have a document which i need to sign and my key resides on a network HSM. Now either I stream the entire document to the HSM to sign or I can create a local hash and stream it to the HSM for encryption alone.
My choice will depend on whether the local hash computation gives me better performance viz a viz delegated hash computation with network latency.

Answer (score 3):

This question is pretty old, but I recently stumbled upon the problem (I'm implementing requirements of some protocol which requires encryption with private key). I will just quote the post from [forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014555794#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014555794):

> I recently stumbled upon the same issue, submitted PMR 22265,49R, and IBM Support after consultation with "development" (whoever those are) ruled that private keys cannot be used for encryption. No matter how much I tried to argue with them that private keys should not be used for data protection, which is only one purpose behind encryption, and that it is perfectly fine to use private keys for encryption to achieve non-repudiation, they were unshakable in their belief. You have got to love people, who insist that 2x2=5.
>
> Here is how I worked around this problem: Essentially, I created a public key object with private key's crypto material. You will need to do the reverse, create a private key object with public key's crypto material, to decrypt with public key if you want to avoid the "Public key cannot be used to decrypt" exception.

```
RSAPrivateCrtKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) ks.getKey(keyAlias, ksPassword.trim().toCharArray());
RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(
   privateKey.getModulus(),
   privateKey.getPrivateExponent()
);
Key fakePublicKey = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, fakePublicKey);
```

Comment: That is very risky if you treat the private key exponent as the public exponent and distribute it, because given the private key (which you are calling the "public key") it is easy to derive the actual public key (which you are now calling the "private key"). Don't accidently let that "public key" out in public, or your system will be compromised. It may be as simple as guessing that the exponent of the "private key" is 65537.

Comment: I was searching for this so long. I'm so thankful for this answer. The name "private and public key" is totally wrong in this use case but there are situations where this is relevant.

Comment: @JimFlood If I understand correctly, and my situation is similar, dmitry created an `RSAPublicKeySpec` to hold the private key data. Obviously he's not going to distribute the private key, just the original public key that can now be used to prove (decrypt) that the private key was for encryption - i.e. non-repudiation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
java.security.Security.addProvider(
                     new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider()
            );
```